# How to get docker Image of a project hosted in Eclipse che workspace?

Tags: docker, eclipse-che

I'm developing a software for ESA scientists. I use Eclipse Che to provide them an IDE for their algorithms and for processing.

But they ask to retrieve docker image of project they created inside a workspace. How could I tell eclipse che to store the docker image of a runned project inside a private docker repository ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform 
docker commit 
And then 
docker push

But you will have to realize which running Docker container is connected to a workspace of a user. You can take a look at container name that should contain workspace id.